# Using pyspark and structured streaming to correctly parse kafka stream (getting all nulls with current schema handling)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am using **Spark 2.3.0** with pyspark to subscribe to a Kafka stream and am currently trying to parse the message values, but getting all null values for each record.

My version of kafka is `kafka_2.11-1.1.0` with broker version being **0.10**.

I am running a script with the following: `/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 ~/code/process/mta_processor.py`

**mta_processor.py** looks like this:

```
import pyspark 
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import bson

sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
spark = SparkSession(sc)


df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "mta-delays") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

jsonschema = StructType().add("timestamp", StringType()) \
                         .add("timestamp_unix", IntegerType()) \
                         .add("oid", StringType()) \
                         .add("lines", ArrayType(StructType() \
                             .add("line", StringType()) \
                            .add("status", StringType()) \
                            .add("raw_text", StringType())))

mta_stream = df.select(from_json(col("value") \
                                .cast("string"), jsonschema) \
                                .alias("parsed_mta_values"))

mta_data = mta_stream.select("parsed_mta_values.*")


qry = mta_data.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
qry.awaitTermination()
```

But the outcome is all null values:

```
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---------+--------------+----+-----+
|timestamp|timestamp_unix| oid|lines|
+---------+--------------+----+-----+
|     null|          null|null| null|
|     null|          null|null| null|
|     null|          null|null| null|
|     null|          null|null| null|
+---------+--------------+----+-----+
```

If I just grab the messages with a `mta_data = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")`

There is data there as I get the key and value with content:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 key|               value|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|5aecc1faeb0155502...|"{\"timestamp_uni...|
|5aecc254eb0155512...|"{\"timestamp_uni...|
|5aecc2b0eb0155545...|"{\"timestamp_uni...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The data that I am sending to my kafka topic from the kafka producer looks like this.

`{
   "timestamp_unix":1525465800,
   "lines":[
      {
         "status":"GOOD SERVICE",
         "line":"123",
         "raw_text":null
      },
      {
         "status":"GOOD SERVICE",
         "line":"456",
         "raw_text":null
      },
      {
         "status":"GOOD SERVICE",
         "line":"7",
         "raw_text":null
      },
      {
         "status":"PLANNED WORK",
         "line":"ACE",
         "raw_text":"\n                    <span class=\"TitlePlannedWork\" >Planned Work</span>\n                    <br/>\n                  <a class=\"plannedWorkDetailLink\" onclick=ShowHide(184938);><b>Rockaways Long-Term Flood Protection | Until May 18, Mon to Fri, 6 AM to 10 AM & 3:30 PM to 8 PM<br clear=left>[A] No service <i>to/from</i> Rockaway Park-Beach 116 St</a><br/><br/><div id= 184938 class=\"plannedWorkDetail\" ><br></b>[A] trains that were scheduled to operate <i>to/from</i> Rockaway Park-Beach 116 St will operate <i>to/from</i> Euclid Av instead.<br><br>[S] No Rockaway Park Shuttle service at Broad Channel.<br><br>[S] Rockaway Park Shuttle operates, <i>approximately every 20 minutes,</i> between <b>Rockaway Park-Beach 116 St</b> and <b>Beach 90 St</b> and via the [A] <i>to/from</i> <b>Far Rockaway-Mott Av</b>.<br><br>For<b> Beach 90 St, Beach 98 St, Beach 105 St</b> and <b>Rockaway Park-Beach 116 St</b>, transfer to the [S] Rockaway Park Shuttle at Beach 67 St.<br><br><a href=http://www.mta.info/press-release/nyc-transit/nyc-transit-starting-subway-flood-protection-project-rockaways-next-month target=_blank><font color=#0000FF>Click here</font></a> for additional details on this Flood Protection Project.<br><br><table class=plannedworkTableStyle  border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=5 rules=none frame=box><td>  [ad]  <td><font size=1>This service change affects one or more ADA accessible stations. Please call 511 for help with planning<br>your trip. If you are deaf or hard of hearing, use your preferred relay service provider or the free 711 relay.  </font></table><br><b><br></div></b><br/>\n                <br/><br/>\n              "
      },
      {
         "status":"DELAYS",
         "line":"BDFM",
         "raw_text":"\n                    <span class=\"TitleDelay\">Delays</span>\n                    <span class=\"DateStyle\">\n                    &nbsp;Posted:&nbsp;05/04/2018&nbsp; 4:29PM\n                    </span><br/><br/>\n                  [F] and [M] train service has resumed following an earlier incident involving a sick passenger at <STRONG>34 St-Herald Sq.</STRONG>\n                <br/><br/>\n              "
      },
      {
         "status":"DELAYS",
         "line":"G",
         "raw_text":"\n                    <span class=\"TitleDelay\">Delays</span>\n                    <span class=\"DateStyle\">\n                    &nbsp;Posted:&nbsp;05/04/2018&nbsp; 4:01PM\n                    </span><br/><br/>\n                  Court Sq-bound [G] trains are running with delays because of signal problems at<STRONG> Broadway</STRONG>.\n                <br/><br/>\n              "
      },
      {
         "status":"GOOD SERVICE",
         "line":"JZ",
         "raw_text":null
      },
      {
         "status":"DELAYS",
         "line":"L",
         "raw_text":"\n                    <span class=\"TitleDelay\">Delays</span>\n                    <span class=\"DateStyle\">\n                    &nbsp;Posted:&nbsp;05/04/2018&nbsp; 4:27PM\n                    </span><br/><br/>\n                  [L] trains are running with delays in both directions because of a sick passenger at <STRONG>Canarsie-Rockaway Pkwy.</STRONG>\n                <br/><br/>\n              "
      },
      {
         "status":"GOOD SERVICE",
         "line":"NQR",
         "raw_text":null
      },
      {
         "status":"PLANNED WORK",
         "line":"S",
         "raw_text":"\n                    <span class=\"TitlePlannedWork\" >Planned Work</span>\n                    <br/>\n                  <a class=\"plannedWorkDetailLink\" onclick=ShowHide(184937);><b>Rockaways Long-Term Flood Protection | Until Friday May 18, 2018<br clear=left>[S] No Rockaway Park Shuttle service at Broad Channel - Take the [A] instead<br clear=left>[A] No rush hour service <i>to/from</i> Rockaway Park-Beach 116 St</a><br/><br/><div id= 184937 class=\"plannedWorkDetail\" ><br></b>[S] Rockaway Park Shuttle operates, <i>approximately every 20 minutes,</i> between <br><b>Rockaway Park-Beach 116 St</b> and <b>Beach 90 St</b> and via the [A] <i>to/from</i> <b>Far Rockaway-Mott Av</b>.<br><br>For <b>Broad Channel</b>, take the [A], transfer to the [S] Rockaway Park Shuttle at Beach 67 St.<br><br><b><i>Alternate travel note for Broad Channel:<br></i>Q52 </b>SBS, <b>Q53 </b>SBS, <b>QM16</b> and <b>QM17</b> service is also available at Cross Bay Blvd and Noel Rd.<br><br><a href=http://www.mta.info/press-release/nyc-transit/nyc-transit-starting-subway-flood-protection-project-rockaways-next-month target=_blank><font color=#0000FF>Click here</font></a> for additional details on this Flood Protection Project.<br><b><br></div></b><br/>\n                <br/><br/>\n              "
      },
      {
         "status":"GOOD SERVICE",
         "line":"SIR",
         "raw_text":null
      }
   ],
   "timestamp":"5/4/2018 4:30:00 PM",
   "oid":"5aecc363eb015557829c87c5"
}`

I am not seeing any obvious error messages or issues on the consumer side to say why all my values are coming out as nulls.

Is there anyway to more easily figure out why it is not parsing values correctly?

**Update:**

It seems like the quotes might be part of the issue. For what it's worth, I have a python dictionary object which is pulled from a mongodb collection and each record is dumped to string with `prepared_record = json.dumps(record)` and then sent with:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', 
                     value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))

producer.send(MTA_DELAYS_IN_KAFKA_TOPIC, key=obj_key.encode(), value=prepared_record).get(timeout=30)
```

Not sure if there's a better way to prepare and send the record.

Comment: Looks like you have some unexpected quotes in your data. I mean `"{\"timestamp_uni...` where it should be `{"timestamp_uni...` in the output. This is something you should fix in the producer (if I am right).

Comment: @user9613318 Hmm i wondered if that would be an issue, but was assuming that the kafka producer was handling that as expected, that is, the json going in is valid and sends properly. Is there something I might consider to better handle the quoting and would that be best on the consumer or the producer side?

Comment: I am not sure if it is quoting alone. Spark doesn't enclose string output with `"`. It suggests that data is produced as `"""\"{"timestamp_unix": "2018-05-04 00:01"}\""""` (literal string) rather than `"""{"timestamp_unix": "2018-05-04 00:01"}"""` document. But I would definitely try to fix it upstream first.

Comment: @user9613318 thanks, currently unsure how to address the issue, updated with information about the producer

Comment: Are you sure that value in Kafka is a dictionary? From the output it looks like it is already a JSON string. Is it fixed when your replace value serializer with `lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, dict) else v.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @user9613318 thanks, that does appear to have resolved the issue, i guess I was going back and forth to much to realize that what I was sending in was getting processed improperly for the stream. If you'd like to prepare that as an answer I can accept it and you can get the credit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. StringType() for each field isn't the correct way.
If one of your datatypes is incorrect, all fields will be shown as null values.
In my case the unix_timestamp wasn't IntegerType() but LongType()

```
jsonschema = StructType().add("timestamp", StringType()) \
                         .add("timestamp_unix", LongType()) \
                         .add("oid", StringType()) \
                         .add("lines", ArrayType(StructType() \
                             .add("line", StringType()) \
                            .add("status", StringType()) \
                            .add("raw_text", StringType())))
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use StringType() for all columns in your jsonschema. For me, it works when changed to StringType()

```
jsonschema = StructType().add("timestamp", StringType()) \
                     .add("timestamp_unix", StringType()) \
                     .add("oid", StringType()) \
                     .add("lines", StringType(StructType() \
                         .add("line", StringType()) \
                        .add("status", StringType()) \
                        .add("raw_text", StringType())))
```